# Import error after including iOS Library

Tags: ios, filepicker.io

I'm trying to include the Ink/FP SDK in my iOS Project (I'm using XCode 5 Developer Preview 3) and the project is building fine prior to including the FPPicker Bundle and Framework, but after including I'm getting the following build error in my Test Project:

'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is specifically related to this SDK because I had the SenTesting framework already linked and working correctly before trying to include the Ink/FP SDK

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not including the SenTestingKit framework. I haven't used xcode 5 yet, but in 4, if you look at the project target under build phases, expand the link that says Link Binary With Libraries, you can click the "+" to add the SenTestingKit.framework. Doing the analogous operation in xcode 5 should resolve your error.

Comment: I had already included SenTestingKit prior to adding the Ink SDK